# adding a space in an image description

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a gallery lightbox with a description of each image 
which getting it from the html
is there a way i can put it in the code so it will give a space to the text or even separate each

in a line 
for example the description text is from :

```
 < p > image title < p > 

< p > image description < p >
```

so the result is showing all in the same line and the same color and the same style 
what should i do to add a space in the popup image description

i put the  `&nbsp;`  and its not working 
thanksss

Comment: didnt understand anything from your question..could you please explain your problem a bit more clearly.

Comment: Is it like that with spaces, or did you just not find out how to format code in questions?

Comment: provide the code and tell us exactly what you want!

Comment: Ditto. I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it looks like you are not closing

image title

. But in fact the problem is "p" tag itself. For proper spacing please consider using "div" tag and then make it proper padding and margin whatever you feel better.

```
<div class="title"> image title </div>
```

and

```
<div class="description"> image description </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin to the paragraph tags using CSS:

```
p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem wasn't the most clear, but it looks like maybe you're trying to add spaces at the beginning/end of the P tags? Could you just add padding to the left and right of the P with CSS?

```
p {
  padding: 0 10px; 
}
```

or inline on the actual P tag...

```
<p style="padding-left: 10px;">
```

If the issue is that it's ignoring the &nbsp character, HTML ignores leading spaces, so you would need to adjust the white-space property with CSS. So for example...

```
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```